# How does one correctly use "q.v."?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations

Wikitionary mentions offhand that "q.v." is used to reference material, but the definition it gives is far too sparse for my taste.  My question is, what does "q.v." stand for and when should one use it? How does it compare with "cf.", for example?

Comment: My favourite example, from the Kurt Vonnegut novel *Jailbird*. The President's Special Advisor on Youth Affairs summarises his unread hundreds of weekly reports in one telegram: "Young people still refuse to see the obvious impossibility of world disarmament and economic equality. Could be fault of New Testament (quod vide)."

Comment: Q. V. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582804/abbreviation-for-further-information-can-be-found

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**q.v.** stands for the phrase   *quod vide* : "on this (matter) go see"

**Cf.** is used chiefly to refer to articles proving or documenting one's point or having authority, not to avoid treating a particular aspect in the course of the writing.

Compared to **cf.**, most authors restrict the  use of **q.v.** to refer to another part of the same work (usually a book) where they treat with the subject matter. This is also used to advise the reader to read another work they endorse.

In a monograph or a large book there is seldom one perfect way of serially organizing all content. **q.v.** is a means for the author to help readers learn more at their leisure.

- without making footnotes
- without distracting or boring people already knowledgeable
- without repeating part of the material

On critical editions, you will sometimes find **q.v.** in margin comments or apostilles as a quick comment for a quote, giving its source.

Comment: Actually **Cf.** (or **cfr.**) can be used to refer to another work as well... It comes from "confronta" which in italian means "compare".

Comment: @Alenanno: I believe this is what I say, I even try to make a recurrence on Cf.

Comment: @Alenanno _Cf._ is not from Italian; it is from Latin _confer_ meaning ‘compare’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, you're right, I don't know why I worded it that way. "Confronta" is the italian corresponding expression for "compare". :)

Comment: @Alenanno, Shouldn't q.v. be used to reference articles instead of cf., since cf. is ambiguous as it could mean "compare/contrast" instead of "refer"?

Comment: What's the difference between **q.v.** and **see**?

Answer (score 8):

To build on the previous answers, the internet has largely replaced usage of the term "q.v." with a hyperlink, which implies that the reader can click it to further inform himself before reading on.  It can still be used, however, to encourage the reader to read it, especially if it contains preliminary material.

> Discussion of the Magi begins in the [previous commentary](http://dailyprayer.us/daily_devotion.php?day=1413) (q.v.).

Comment: Is cf accepted usage here? Eg. "Discussion of the Magi begins in the previous commentary (c.f.)."

Comment: I don't know where "here" is, but in your example you would use q.v.  The best I know, "cf." always takes an object to which on wants to compare the antecedent word or phrase.  Also note, it is "cf." not "c.f."

Comment: I used to be a lawyer and it has a very specific and nuanced meaning when used in a brief or law review article. Cf. is used when the cited authority supports a proposition different from the main proposition but sufficiently analogous to lend support.  It is more directly supportive than "see generally" but less than "see also".

Answer (score 4):

This is what my NOAD says:

> **q.v.**
>   Abbreviation
>   Used to direct a reader to another part of a book or article for further information.
>
> ORIGIN from Latin **quod vide**, literally ‘which see.’

We can say that the meaning is something like "go to see...". Give a look at [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=QesIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA703&dq=q.v.%20names%20surnames&hl=en&ei=rEfNTan3C4Kh8QOJ_qT1DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-preview-link&resnum=7&ved=0CGUQuwUwBg#v=onepage&q=q.v.&f=false).

Comment: I know you asked for "when should I use it", I'm looking for some book examples... :) I'll edit the answer as soon as I find something.

Comment: Per your comment in another answer, Why can't c.f. be used in these cases?

Comment: +1 for including the literal translation.  In my opinion, this is 95% of the answer all by itself.  You should use "q.v." wherever "which [you should] see" would make sense.

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, I don't think I ever saw your comment. Which comment of mine are you referring to?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I found it. But that's not what I said in the comment.

Comment: I mean: you stated the meaning of `q.v.` is *"go to see..."* and you also stated that `cf.` *"can be used to refer to another work as well..."*. **So,** why can't `cf.` to be used to mean  *"go to see..."*?

Comment: @pacerier that's not the literal meaning, but in a sense it's saying something like that. "Compare" and "go to see" are not that far apart.

Comment: @Alenanno, "compare" and "go to see" have quite distinct features actually... one says  "compare what is just said with X" while the other says "see this link for more info on X". Completely different meaning.

Answer (score 4):

**Cf.** stands for the Latin word *confer* (not the Italian *confronta*), and means "bring together", or more loosely translated, "hold what I just said next to this other thing".

Example:

> We shouldn't eat dogs, because they are cute (cf. rabbits).

**Q.v.** generally means something more along the lines of, "I talk more about this over here", or "if you don't know what this means, this other book is a good introduction."

In David Foster Wallace's "Infinite Jest", the deliberately over-academic footnotes (and footnotes to the footnotes) are full of *q.v.*’s, generally used ironically to emphasize trivial information about the novel's fictional future US/Canada/Mexico super-nation, O.N.A.N. A lengthy footnote (#24) lists all the experimental films made by the protagonist’s father and is frequently referred back to in later footnotes as these films appear in the plot; for example:

> Wayne's not-to-be-fucked-with papa eventually litigated the kid's segment out because the film had the word Homo in the title, q.v. note 24.

Comment: Note that the David Foster Wallace example quoted here is actually a **misuse** of _q.v._ The way it's used here, it ought to be _cf._ instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet According to the definition given in this answer, I think DFW's use of *q.v.* ("see further") is more correct than *cf.* ("compare").

Comment: @sjy ‘See further’ is not what _q.v._ means; it means ‘which see’, that is, “which you can look up for details”. The ‘which’ part is anaphoric and refers back to something previous. So you can say “described in note 24 (q.v.)”, but not “q.v. note 24”. _Q.v._ is especially used in dictionaries after cross-references to headwords, e.g., “**sloe** the fruit of the blackthorn (q.v.)”, which is a reference to _blackthorn_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the clarification! I actually learned *q.v.* from *Infinite Jest*, and I had always thought it was *semantically* distinct from *cf.* (which suggests a comparison or distinction between the topic of discussion and the cited source). The other answers don't make this explicit, but I now realise there is a *syntactic* distinction as well (q.v. doesn't take an object, except when DFW uses it).

Answer (score 4):

To be frank, most of the answers here I do not find appealing.

*q.v.* and *cf.* basically mean both the same: "see here" or "compare with this". This means that there is actually a third candidate in the ring often found in literature: *see*

If you want to make a distinction the following is what I have learned (and adopted):

*q.v.* is used predominantly for a reference *in the same work*. That is, if you write a book or article and you want to refer to another place *in this very book or article you are currently writing*, then you say "q.v. section 3.2 below" or "q.v. page 12 above".

*cf.* is often used as an almost equivalent to *see* (about the difference, q.v. below). It usually refers to (a passage in) *another publication* (by another author or yourself). That is if you write a book or article and say something which is either supported by what someone else has already said (or yourself) in an earlier work, or if what you have just written is further explained and elaborated upon *in another work* by someone else (or yourself), you write "cf. the argument in Smith 1992" or "cf. the fuller discussion in my book *Superbook*".

*see* (and *see also*) is often used as an almost equivalent to *cf.* and thus refers to (a passage in) *another publication* (by another author or yourself). If people draw a distinction between *cf.* and *see*, then the following is the rule: *cf.* is more for a comparison, that is it can refer to something which either supports what you have just written or actually doesn't – in any way it is something that should be compared to (and evaluated in the lights of) what you have just written. *see (also)* however should only refer to an earlier publication that makes the same point as you are just doing now.

In short: "see the same argument in Smith 1998" – "cf. the slightly different translation in Miller 1978" (and "cf. the nonsense written by Miller") – "q.v. my discussion below".

Answer (score 3):

Use `q.v.` when your text names a work or an author and you think the reader might benefit from consulting that source.

> As Buckley wrote in *God And Man At Yale* (q.v.), ...

Answer (score -3):

Hm, I don't like any of these answers.

q.v. (quod vide) is best translated into Modern English as "see also" and should be used when the reference is a continuation or expansion of the current subject.

c.f. (con ferro) is best translated as "compare with" and should be used when the reference is an analogue to the subject-at-hand, presenting a similar paradigm or otherwise analogous subject matter.

Comment: You’ve basically said nothing in this answer that has not already been said, except to give an incorrect etymology of _cf._ (not _c.f._, which means ‘carried forward’ in accounting) and state that _q.v._ is for “when the reference is a continuation or expansion of the current subject”, which is not necessarily true.