# How to abbreviate “compare”, “see”, “refer to”

Tags: abbreviations

In my native language (Italian) there are convenient abbreviations for *compare* (*cfr*) and *see* or *refer to* (*vd*). Is there anything similar in English? Or should I just use the complete words *see* or *refer to* in these cases?

I am referring to something that I can use in an informal note, where citations and bibliography seem an overkill.

E.g:

The method they developed gave better results respect the traditional methods (*cfr* “Traditional methods for the task”)

The results for those experiments (*vd* paragraph “Those Experiments”) show a direct correlation between A and B.

Comment: I wonder, why you want to abbreviate "see"? For compare you could use *cmp* which is regularly used in computer science. However, I'm not sure if it is used in formal context too.

Comment: I tried to search cmp on merriamwebster but I didn't find it. I want to express something like:
- see that for the detailed description
- compare that with what I am saying

Comment: @Em1 One reason: Not so much to abbreviate as to set out from normal text, so the reader would not confuse the word *see* to be part of the narrative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In formal, and mostly older, academic texts in English you may sometimes see *cf* (compare) and *vid* (see), but they are not used elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have updated my question, is it good to always repeat the words "see" and "refer to" in these cases?

Comment: Yes, in an informal text you have to repeat the complete words, or find alternatives.

Comment: Meta question: Should we take care to always avoid using cf. on ELU? (Okay, I *may* have to ask this on meta.)

Comment: @Kris: I take care to avoid Latin abbreviations wherever possible.

Comment: @Kris,Barrie: According to a site-specific Google search, "cf" occurs 907 times on ELU. Some of those are probably mine. I don't see a problem - if the reader isn't familiar with the usage, he can safely ignore "cf" completely without losing anything significant from the meaning of the text.

Comment: You may also see *qv* (*quod vide*), meaning “which see”.

Answer (score 5):

In formal legal citation in the US, *cf.* is always used for *compare* when it means *support by analogy*. See this [article](http://www.access-to-law.com/citation/basic_legal_citation.pdf), Section 6-300(a).

However, there is no short form for *see* in legal cites.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are asking in the context of technical/ scientific literature. In such a case there are some standard ways of referencing. Depending on the publication and other factors, you may be required to follow a certain style guide such as CMoS, please check with the publishers.

APA Style Guide recommends [*cf*: compare (inside parentheses only)](http://blog.apastyle.org/files/apa-latin-abbreviations-table-2.pdf) (pdf 20kB)

Comment: Thank you, but my question is more for common language usage. I am aware of bibliography formatting and reference styles. I am just curious to know what is common in English, in contexts like note-taking

Comment: Your examples are not from 'common language usage', where *see* is the norm, if not the rule.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this isn't really common language... I am writing an email with notes on a research paper (but I am not writing part of a thesis or an article) ..those sentences where in my mind at the moment and I couldn't think of other more general examples!

Comment: Anyway, I thought you were just talking about references styles like [1] or (Kris et al 2012). But I've seen the updated answer, thank you for the reference

Answer (score 1):

Another similar abbreviation is qv or q.v. (in latin literally "which see"), used when you want to direct the reader to another article or publication. Example usage:

> *q.v.* [How does one correctly use "q.v."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25252/how-does-one-correctly-use-q-v)