# Latin equivalent for "see" (reference)

Tags: latin, reference

One of my references is an audio file.  It feels funny to say

> bla bla bla (see such-and-so audio recordings).

Is there some Latin I could use in place of "see"?

Comment: The abbreviation "Cf." is Latin for "confer" which means "compare" and is a different signal than "see" but not entirely different. "e.g." means "for example" and "i.e." means "in other words." While "id." or "ibid" means the same source as previously referred to, and "passim" means used throughout the work. "Accord" has a close meaning to "see" and is formal but not latin. These kinds of words are called citation signals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_signal Also consider "viz" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.

Comment: Check out <http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88059/how-to-abbreviate-compare-see-refer-to>. You might want to consider *ref.*, which is an abbreviation for *reference*.

Comment: @RichardKayser - Do I use italics or regular text?

Comment: Regular text according to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ref. There must be a better source, but I couldn't readily find a better one. Have a good night.

Comment: There's this one: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ref_3 It's ambiguous with regard to plain text or italics, but I think it points in the direction of plain text. Unfortunately, examples are usually in italics.

Comment: @RichardKayser - I used your "ref." idea because I know that lawyers use a lot of Latin, and I was afraid of misusing *vide*, and I also wanted to keep my general style down to earth.  If the question hadn't been closed I would have asked you to post *ref.* as an answer so I could accept it.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. It's a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

**vide**

> See; consult (used as an instruction in a text to refer the reader to a specified passage, book, author, etc., for further information):

*'vide the comments cited in Schlosser'*

*'Indeed, she was no mean composer herself, vide her full-length opera The Smugglers of Penzance.'*

–[Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vide), which includes other example uses

A lot of English readers may not know what *vide* means, but you did ask for a Latin word. It can be abbreviated as **v.** according to the *Chicago Manual of Style*. Meanwhile [Cf](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cf.) literally and traditionally means *to compare*, not *to consult*.