# Saxon genitive and "et al."

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, saxon-genitive

I am writing a scientific paper. In this context, it is usual to cite other works with the last name of the first author followed by "et al." when there are many. If I want to use a possessive form, how should I use the Saxon genitive?

For example, is "Smith's et al." correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, *et al.* should be in *italics*. That said, the common way to refer to a publication like that would be:

> Smith and coworkers'...

or

> Smith and colleagues'

*Et al.* means *and others*, it is an [abbreviation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/et+al.) of the latin *et alii*. If you really really wanted to use it in the possessive, you would write

> Smith *et al*'s

but don't do that, it is ugly and unclear. Paraphrase, use *and coworkers* or similar constructs.

Comment: Shouldn't it be **Smith and coworkers'**?

Comment: What about the dot? Smith _et al_.'s ?

Comment: Forget the dot.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան ouch, yes, of course it should, thanks.

Comment: 'Coworkers' strikes me as rather dumbed-down English to use in such circumstances, especially with a Latin phrase. (How much milk might they have produced?) It is not much used at all in Britain. What is wrong with 'colleagues'?

Comment: _Et alii_ would stand for male coworkers only; therefore, this being a scientific paper, _et al._, if used, would mean _et alia_. Unless the study was undertaken in one of those men's colleges...

Comment: Coworkers always looks too much like cow-workers for my liking!

Comment: @TaliaFord thanks, I was just repeating what I learned in the link I gave, I have no Latin whatsoever. That said, the term hails from a time when science was published only by men and those few women who were doing science would have to hide behind their spouses or use pseudonyms so so it probably is indeed an abbreviation of _et alli_.

Comment: @WS2 _colleagues_ is fine as well. Both are used in scientific papers.

Comment: People do write `'s` after *et al.*  (I don't actually think it's ugly or unclear, but that's just me.)

Comment: @TaliaFord: You seem to be saying that unidentified authors are neuter rather than masculine. If so, I don't think you're right either in Latin or English.

Comment: @TimLymington I don't think I seem to be saying that. There's grammar, and then there's usage. Grammatically speaking, you're right: m.pl. _alii_, f.pl. _aliae_, n.pl. _alia_. However, pragmatically speaking, people use the neuter gender when the sex of a plural referent is unknown. They just do, by convention.

Comment: @TaliaFord they do? I haven't had the privilege of observing native Latin speakers in conversation :). Joking apart, many languages use the neuter for mixed sex groups so I imagine Latin does so as well, this is not really relevant to this Q&A though since the abbreviation in question does seem to come from the male form, which is understandable given the historical context.

Comment: @terdon It's simple: if you were asked by your editor to expand the abbreviation _et al._ in the context of the op, what would you write? You should write _et alia_, because that's what people do. That the originating language is formally dead and that _et al._ ages ago was an abbreviation only for _et alii_, are irrelevant for the now.

Comment: @TaliaFord so you're saying that I should change what abbreviations stand for to better fit the times? Perhaps but I find that strange, an abbreviation has a specific meaning, I would not consider it correct to adapt that. Would you also correct _hoi polloi_ to _ta polla_ to make it neuter? Greek of course uses the male and not the neuter when the sex in unknown so this might not be the best example, did Latin really use the neuter?

Comment: First, I'm not saying _et al._ should be expanded. But, if you were asked to (for whatever reason), it is not I who's saying that in some context you should use _alia_, but WordNet 3.0 is, Webster's (2010) is, and OED (1989) is, and so is COCA. Second, I was considering **an abbreviation**, not "abbreviations." Your _hoi polloi_ thus ends up acting as a straw man as big as the Wicker Man. Last, I dunno in which c. _et alia_ gained a foothold, but it's inconsequential whether it did while Latin was still alive. Today, the convention is _et alia_; you can break it,but you _will_ be breaking it.

Comment: @TaliaFord: Do you have some evidence to support that ? Collins, for example (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/et-al) says clearly that it stands for *et alii*.

Comment: [wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=et+al.](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=et+al.), [definitions.uslegal.com/e/et-alia](http://definitions.uslegal.com/e/et-alia), [www.wordwebonline.com/en/ETALIA](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ETALIA), [english.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/et-cetera-vs-et-al](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/et-cetera-vs-et-al). But yes, some dictionaries, Collins not being the only one, are adhering to the old way of things, which I didn't know until a moment ago. So, sure, you go the old way if you must. I won't.

Comment: [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=et+al.) says: *abbreviation of Latin et alii (masc.), et aliæ (fem.), or et alia (neuter), in any case meaning "and others."*