# Should "et al." be in italics?

Tags: italics

Should "et al." be written in italics, or not?

My impression was that it was, but http://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/commonerrors.html and http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/et-al-when-and-how.html says it should not be italicised, but I previously thought it should be, as does this [side-remark in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/132427/1420).

Comment: Yes it is not necessary to italicize it.

Comment: It is often written in italics (as are other Latin expressions), but I think that this is a matter of style. In science, it clearly depends on the journal. Note that for some reason, "e.g." and "i.e." are not printed in italics even in journals that use italics for "et al.".

Comment: Relat5ed (possible dupe): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1289/8019.

Comment: @TimLymington the accepted answer of that question has only a single sentence on italicisation of foreign words.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Chicago Manual of Style, 16th ed. (p.365) says that commonly used Latin words and abbreviations **should not be italicized**, and lists "et al." as an example.

Comment: Any idea about other style guides, whether they recommend the same. or the contrary? Would be interesting to get a broader overview...